# EL ${string+variable+string}

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

**i want to output this eg:**

```
<c:if test="${tPriceList_priceListValue_0__salesPrice}">true</c:if>
```

**question:**
**how can i make this work**

```
<c:if test="${tPriceList_priceListValue_${index}__salesPrice}">true</c:if>
```

**ps:'index' is variable.**

i try `${'tPriceList_priceListValue_'index'__salesPrice'}` not work

```
${'tPriceList_priceListValue_'+index+'__salesPrice'} not work
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you know the scope of this variable beforehand, and assuming that it's the request scope, then this approach of first preparing the key as another variable via `<c:set>`, and then using it as dynamic map key by brace notation `${map[key]}` should do:

```
<c:set var="salesPrice" value="tPriceList_priceListValue_${index}__salesPrice" />
<c:if test="${requestScope[salesPrice]}">true</c:if>
```

Other scopes have their own maps as well, in case your variable is actually stored over there: `${pageScope}`, `${sessionScope}` and `${applicationScope}`.

Comment: +1 The reason, why you have to use EL (the ${index}) and JSTL (c:set), is that EL doesn't have append operator for strings.